# Is there a method for email notification on insert,update or delete record from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

I want email notification on insert,update or delete record from mysql. I dont know about trigger. I have google and found solution in below link

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/283177/how-to-get-real-time-notifications-when-a-database-change-insert-update-dele

But this not run in mytable. Please guide me for this point.

Comment: [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/283177/how-to-get-real-time-notifications-when-a-database-change-insert-update-dele) might help.